# Simple webcam chat on actionscript 3?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, networking, chat, webcam

Could someone provide me the guidings to creating a simple webcam chat on actionscript? Do flash already have a webcam object? How could I exchange the video stream between 2 clients?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, refer to following classes:

1. [Camera](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Camera.html), [Microphone](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Microphone.html). Class which allows you to manipulate with the camera.
2. [NetStream](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html), [NetConnection](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetConnection.html). These classes are used for establishing connection and manipulating data/media streams.
3. [Video](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Video.html), [Sound](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Sound.html). Playing video and sound.

Then, you should check, whether you're going to use p2p technology, or use media server:

1. [Adobe Cirrus](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/cirrus/) - Adobe p2p technology.
2. [FMS](http://www.adobe.com/products/flashmediaserver/), [Wowza](http://www.wowza.com/), [Red5](http://www.red5.org)(open source), etc. Media servers.

Take a look at documentation, examples and guids refering the links.